# Custom UITableViewCell, initial view gets removed when reordering

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom cell which looks like this

Cell

-ContainingView (called cellframe)

--Label

--Label

The reason for the containing view is so that I can set a shadow around the cell.

below is my code

```
#import "QuickNoteMasterViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface QuickNoteMasterViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;

@end



@implementation QuickNoteMasterViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing{

}

// this adds shadow and border to the cell

- (void)configureBackgroundView
{
    UIView *cellFrame = self.cellFrame;
    //cellFrame.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    //cellFrame.layer.borderWidth = 10.;

    CGSize size = cellFrame.bounds.size;
    CGFloat curlFactor = 15.0f;
    CGFloat shadowDepth = 5.0f;
    cellFrame.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cellFrame.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.f;
    cellFrame.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(.0f, 3.0f);
    cellFrame.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    cellFrame.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, 0.0f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, size.height + shadowDepth)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, size.height + shadowDepth)
            controlPoint1:CGPointMake(size.width - curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)
            controlPoint2:CGPointMake(curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)];
    cellFrame.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self configureBackgroundView];

}



@end
```

[image: before drag]

The problem is that when I reorder the cells, the ContainingView (called cellframe)
gets removed.

[image: during drag]

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a UITableViewCell is reordered, the TableView will hide everything that's not a UILabel or UIImageView.

Not quite sure why it does this, but I don't know of any way around it.
The only way I know will work is to create your shadowed view as an image and switching your UIView for a UIImageView.

Sorry!

Comment: Shame! I have thought of a solution but i've struggled to implement it. Basically I need to draw the white rectange, in the container's layer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I do custom cells I add my own customView to fill the entire cell and do all my drawing/custom requirements in that view, then you have full control.

Also on willDisplayCell you can instruct your a method on your custom cell to re-implement your shadow etc.

```
– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: but the custom view is getting removed on drag. So i'm having to do the drawing in UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: what more do you wish to see? the rest it designed in IB

Comment: Ah I think you might need to work with your custom views more in code, that is definitely what I do as soon as I want more control.

Check out my project on Github RHTableViewProvider, it has custom drawing of cells all handled there, any bugs with it let me know if you use it :)

https://github.com/robinhayward/RHTableViewProvider